# Facebook Real-time Updates is not posting data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-2

I have set up the real time subscription for facebook, the subscription is done successfully but I am only getting friends updates if friends are added or removed, apart from this I am not getting anything for like "books, checkins, work, education etc...". Facebook is sending the Token to my web server. That is good so far. My server sends back the response to facebook. So far Configuration is done successfully.

Another Issue is - I am not able to see the incomming request in Fiddler. I have tried below to check the incomming request...

```
if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "IP Address:8888") 
    oSession.host = "IP Address:Port Number";
```

Comment: Is the attached code from fiddler? Why did you added this line? About updates maybe you didn't configure it right. Check out this http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/21/bringing-real-time-updates-to-the-app-dashboard/

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes (especially with IE) Fiddler has to be started before you start your debugging session.